# What is the definition for totally ramified extension for a global field?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

What is the definition for totally ramified extension for a global field?
For local fields it means the maximal prime ideal generated from the uniformizer totally ramifies. But what is the definition for an algebraic number field?

Answer (score 4):

If $K$ is a global field, $p$ is a prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$, and $L/K$ is an extension with $n=[L:K]$, we say that $p$ is totally ramified in $L$ (or that $L$ is totally ramified at $p$) if $p\mathcal{O}_L=q^n$ for some prime $q$ of $L$.

However, since of course there are many primes of $K$, it's not a complete statement to **only** say *"The field $L$ is totally ramified over $K$"*, you have to specify which prime you're talking about – alternatively, the statement could just mean *"There exists at least one prime $p$ of $K$ that is totally ramified in $L$"*.

Comment: Yes this is the definition for a prime $p$ of $K$ to be totally ramified but I would like to know the definition for when do we say that a global field $L$ is totally ramified extension of $K$.

Comment: I would assume it means *"There exists at least one prime $p$ of $K$ that is totally ramified in $L$"*, which I've added to my answer.

Comment: What I found is located in one paper https://eudml.org/doc/89385 where the author says extension $L$ is totally ramified over $K$ if there exists no subextension other than $K$ itself which is unramified over $K$. Is this definition available in literature anywhere else? I would like to know more of such type of extensions.